Autotransformer vs Rheostat
Autotransformers and rheostats are both based on the wire wound into helical shape, a coil with cylindrical shape, and (minimum) 3 taps.
Is it possible to use them interchangeably? Autotransformers as rheostats, and vice versa?
I suppose that not. But why not? What is the difference between their construction (not between their functionality)?
EDIT:
It seems that I didn't clearly express, what interests me:
Two devices, an autotransformer and a rheostat, both made from a wire, both have 3 taps, what is the substantial difference e.g. from the point of a manufacturer?
Substantial — not something as a presence of the core or a fixed vs. sliding tap.
EDIT 2:
I meant a particular rheostat, based on the wire wound into helical shape and with 3 available taps (2 of them fixed, on both ends of the wire).

I've rolled this question back to remove the tag "potentiometer" (not a question about potentiometers and causes contradictions in answers already given).

@Andy aka, OP is talking about a rheostat with three terminals which is a potentiometer.

@Circuitfantasist no, the OP is confused at to what a rheostat is and your change to his question (now rolled back) just added misery to the confusion.

Let's clear up the terms. A universal variable resistor has three terminals (the middle one is a wiper). When used with two terminals (one end and the middle), it's known as a "rheostat". This allows for current regulation. If all three terminals are used, it's called a "potentiometer". This can be used to regulate voltage.

Autotransformers are, as the name suggests, transformers and for efficiency use an iron core to maximise and steer the magnetic flux in a closed loop.
Rheostats are resistors and, generally, designed to minimise parasitic properties such as inductance and capacitance. For ease of construction they can be wound on a tubular (non-ferrous) air-cored former but many are wound on ceramic.

Figure 1. Rheostat on ceramic core by EEPower.
From the EEPower website:

A rheostat is a variable resistor which is used to control current. They are able to vary the resistance in a circuit without interruption. The construction is very similar to the construction of potentiometers. It uses only two connections, even when 3 terminals (as in a potentiometer) are present. The first connection is made to one end of the resistive element and the other connection to the wiper (sliding contact). In contrast to potentiometers, rheostats have to carry a significant current. Therefore ,they are primarily constructed as wirewound resistors. Resistive wire is wound around an insulating ceramic core and the wiper slides over the windings.

Autotransformers have several advantages over rheostats.

They are more efficient. Power losses are low.
Transformers give an output voltage that remains reasonably constant across a range of secondary load currents.

Rheostats are rather different.

The output voltage is not constant. It will vary from full supply voltage at zero amps (as there will be no voltage drop with zero current) to an ever decreasing output voltage as the current increases.
The voltage drop across the resistor generates heat. P = VI = V2/R = I2R where P is the power dissipated (watts), V is the voltage drop across the resistor and I is the current through the resistor.


From the comments:

My question was ... about construction (something as the wire diameter, for example).

Transformers use wires of low resistance to minimise power dissipated as heat. These are almost always copper (for its balance of cost, availability, resistance, ease of insulation and workability) but can be aluminium on larger (> many kW). There will be a trade off between reducing resistance and the bulk of the wire and space it takes up.
Rheostats use resistance wire to maximise power dissipated as heat.
Transformers and rheostats are completely different and there is little in common in the design and manufacture of the two components.

Thanks for your very nice answer, but iron core of transformer is not the substantial (it increases efficiency, but in principle it may be without the core). My question was not about principle of work, too, but about construction (something as the wire diameter, for example). Please, may you add this info?

See the update.

Thanks, now you hit the nail on the head!

You've simplified it to them both being coils of wire with taps, but that's about where their similarity ends. Also I think that when you say auto-transformer you may be meaning Variac, which is a variable auto-transformer.
An auto-transformer is typically wound with magnet wire, copper wire that has an insulating epoxy coating on it so that the wire can be wound in layers without the turns shorting out to each other. Copper wire is used to keep the resistance low to keep down losses. The main idea of an auto-transformer is to use the mutual inductance of the windings to transform an AC voltage to a higher or lower AC voltage, so you want to maximize the coupling between the turns, generally by winding them on an iron or ferrite core.
A rheostat is wound with resistance wire, wire that is made from an alloy that gives it much higher resistance than a copper wire of the same size. The wire is wound around a form not to give it more inductance but simply to get more wire length in a smaller space. You could take the wire, stretch it out, connect to one end and a wiper that runs along the length of the wire and it would still act like a rheostat, it just wouldn't be very convenient to use.

Very nice answer, you understood my question. Thanks, and — of course — voting up!

The purpose of the iron/ferrite core is more about vastly increasing the overall inductivity of the transformer (and thus the AC resistance against an imbalance between primary and secondary currents weighted by windings).  It also allows physical separation between primary and secondary windings which makes the overheating scenario less dangerous for humans (if not for the transformer).


Is it possible to use them interchangeably? Autotransformers as
rheostats, and vice versa?

Not at all.
An autotransformer uses magnetic fields to create different voltages with very little power loss. Pretty much how a regular transformer works but without primary-secondary isolation.
A rheostat is a two terminal variable resistor that uses power dissipation as a means of dropping voltage. The two devices are not similar despite sometimes superficially looking the same.
For instance, a carbon tile rheostat is a 2 terminal variable resistor that uses carbon tiles (or blocks) and a vice type compression arrangement: -

Image source
In other words, a Rheostat does not necessarily use wires. Whereas an autotransformer must use wire and a ferrous core to contain the magnetism used to transfer energy. An autotransformer is usually a 3 terminal device.

Thanks for your answer, but my question was not about principle of work, but about construction (i.e. for example the wire diameter). Please, may you add this info?

I quoted your question in my answer and, addressed it by saying "not at all". Additionally I pointed out that your definition of what constitutes a rheostat is incorrect.

You're right, you quoted my question, but after it, I expressed my opinion and put a second question. The answer for the last is what interests me.

@MarianD but the problem is that a rheostat can be made from carbon blocks and a vice arrangement. Rheostats don't necessarily get made from wire at all. In other words, a rheostat has two terminals and not a minimum of three and, a rheostat is not necessarily made using wires. In other words you are not in any way comparing apples with apples.

Yes, a rheostat can be made from carbon block, but it is not the basis of my question. It seems that I didn't clearly express, what interests me. Two devices, an autotransformer and a rheostat, both made from a wire, both have 3 taps, what is the substantial difference e.g. from the point of a manufacturer?

@MarianD A rheostat by definition has two connections and never three. If it has three connections then it's a potentiometer. Then you said this in your question: Autotransformers and rheostats are both based on the wire wound into helical shape and that is wrong because some rheostats are made from carbon blocks. I don't know why you are arguing when your question clearly contains a misconception about rheostats.

@MarianD A rheostat is a two terminal arrangement. (Even though the "other end" of the resistor terminal is often also available for potentiometer wiring)

@Andy aka, you're completely right, my fault in the poor formulated question.:-( Perhaps the better one would begin with "Let's assume 2 particular devices, a variable autotransformer, and a rheostat based on the wire wound into helical shape with 3 terminals (many of them have 3 terminals, in spite of using only 2 of them for the current reduction)."

Very good observation...
If we consider the fact that the conductor used to wind the transformer coil has some resistance, we can say:
Yes, we can use them interchangeably but only in one direction - the autotransformer as a potentiometer.
With this seemingly absurd statement, one of my former university friends put his high school electronics teacher in an awkward situation in the 80s when he was a "non-standard" student. She never understood what the idea was because she thought traditionally...

Thanks, you're the only one who clearly answered my first question.

"Yes, we can use them interchangeably but only in one direction - the autotransformer as a potentiometer." while staying significantly below the operating frequency of the autotransformer and having ridiculously low power specs for the size and weight.  Kind of like being able to use scissors as a hammer but not vice versa.

@user107063, It's just like a curiosity that makes us think unconventionally.  Otherwise, the low resistance of the copper wire limits it to low values ​​of the (DC and AC) voltage.

For starters, a rheostat is a two-terminal device and an autotransformer is a three-terminal one, but overlooking that and comparing a potentiometer with an autotransformer, we have the following situation:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
For sake of convenience, both at set to 50 %. Feel free to play around with the values. A 200 ohm potentiometer with a 10 W rating (size of a golf ball) would only allow 500 mA to flow before you've hit its rating. The upside is that it does the same for AC as DC, so very useful in a wide variety of applications where the current is low. Control signals mostly.
An autotransformer on the other hand has inductance, which means you need to supply it with AC as the winding resistance is too low (on normal ones) to be used for DC voltage division. The current however can be much higher as you're not burning away the losses and you are limited by the volt-second product of your core and thus primary input voltage at a given frequency.

Thanks for your answer, it is the closest one to my answer. Did I correctly understand that the main difference is in inductance? Moreover, I don't understand resistors R3 and R4 in your schematic, are there really present in real autotransformers?

@MarianD R3 and R4 are winding resistance. If you keep the voltage very low, it functions even for DC due to it, but the point of it is low losses for AC use so allows you to run it at high power.

Autotransformers can be also step-up.

Your "equivalence" diagram is utterly misrepresenting autotransformers since the decisive thing is that the magnetic flux between the two inductivities is strongly coupled meaning that the inductivity causing low currents for AC power is essentially absent for current differences between L1 and L2, meaning that you can draw large output currents without inducing relevant voltage changes at the output.  Uncoupled inductivities would not be able to pass vastly more real than apparent power.

@user107063 I'll update it with coupled inductors on a core.
